# How to see what are all the methods in deployed contract response via Hardhat

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, ethers.js, hardhat

```
  const simpleStorageFactory = await hre.ethers.deployContract("SimpleStorage");
  await simpleStorageFactory.waitForDeployment();
  console.log("simpleStorageFactory",await simpleStorageFactory)
  console.log("Deploying....");
  console.log(`Deployed contract to ${await simpleStorageFactory.getAddress() }`)
```

I tried by console in line 3 but can't get!

Comment: Check the documentation https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/contract/#BaseContract-waitForDeployment. It is the deployed contract.